# Storing HTML Wysiwyg Editor data

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg

I am developing a Webapp with a Wysiwyg editor with [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). Now I am facing the problem of how to store the data in the database. I mean, the data generated by the editor is in HTML. Should I store the data direcly in HTML? If I store only the text, how to get the tags to render the info when the page is refreshed? Thanks.

PD: The data from the editor is caught by a Javascript function.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
parsed_html = $.parseHTML( html_text );
```

However, I'm unsure whether you can store the parsed text in a database or not. I store them as raw html and then at display I convert them.

Comment: If you have large HTML pages isn't it slow?

Comment: Could be, but i also store images as text with the base64image plugin and even that is rendered in an instant.

Comment: can u please create a demo for this

Answer (score 1):

I think you should store data directly in HTML so you can keep text format when render.

If you want to store text data only, using textarea or textbox is easier.